# SSH into a virtual machine on the local network

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines

I have Ubuntu running in Parallels on my iMac with the Network setting (Under Hardware > Network 1) set to Shared Network. I found the IP address of the VM and am able to SSH into it from the iMac. I tried to SSH into it from my laptop that is on the same wireless home network and am unable to connect. Is there some other setting I need to do in order to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Shared Network" in Parallels lingo means that your iMac is doing NAT on behalf of the VM. You probably want "Bridged Mode", with which your VM will get an IP address from your router via DHCP.

Comment: Thanks. It was `vinc0` under Bridged Network.